# How can I replace values ​in an array?

Tags: r, arrays, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have an array of 1 and 2, I need to change the values ​​2 to 0 but I know how to do it. Someone who can help me with the code in R. Thanck

Comment: `my_array[my_array == 2] <- 0`

Answer (score 3):

You can try `%%`

```
arr <- arr %% 2
```

or `replace`

```
replace(arr, arr == 2, 0),
```

or just `-`

```
2 - arr
```

or a faster version with `bitwAnd`

```
arr <- bitwAnd(arr, 1)
```

---

## Benchmark

```
set.seed(1)
arr <- sample(1:2, 1e6, replace = TRUE)
microbenchmark(
  arr %% 2,
  replace(arr, arr == 2, 0),
  2 - arr,
  bitwAnd(arr, 1),
  check = "equivalent"
)
```

gives

```
Unit: milliseconds
                      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq
                    arr%%2 10.874101 11.269351 12.689352 11.537851 13.611351
 replace(arr, arr == 2, 0)  9.174002  9.542651 11.347834 10.070752 13.385150
                   2 - arr  1.477701  1.548151  3.076632  1.612951  1.981701
           bitwAnd(arr, 1)  1.322300  1.368951  1.678158  1.413750  1.537602
       max neval
 24.764601   100
 16.579201   100
 61.927400   100
  6.053701   100
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is about arrays I want to expand a little to a more general case where you want to replace only certain dimension or one dimension according to another dimension.

```
set.seed(1)
arr <- array(data=sample(1:2, 24, replace = TRUE), dim=c(2,3,4))

# replace all 2 values
arr[arr==2] <- 0

# replace only first index of dimension 1
arr[1,,][arr[1,,]==2] <- 0

# replace second index according to first index of dimension 1
arr[2,,][arr[1,,]==2] <- 0
```